# In magento 1.9.0.1 in checkout payment Information is not working

Tags: php

I am unable to proceed payment information. When I click on continue in one step checkout even though I added fieldset id.

```
var payment = new Payment('co-payment-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onestep/savePayment') ?>');
var onestep = new Onestep( '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveCart') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', 'checkoutSteps');
```

Comment: You forgot to add the image.

Comment: We need to see some code, we can't do much without

Comment: sir since i dont have 10 reputations i am unable to post images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U better go with Onepage checkout settings where you will get more options Such as Shipping to Multi addresses and Changing the delivery address while doing payment...If you are doing Onepage checkout means You will have to copy the files from frontend/base/default path and there You need to modify the content .